# Conditional dependency settings in SBT using inTask(...)

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt

I am using spark and I want to be able to execute jobs both local and remotely from InteliJ. My dependency settings are

```
  lazy val sparkDependencies = Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
  ).map(_ % "provided")
   .map(_.excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.scala-lang")))
```

When I tried to run a class from the IDE I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
```

I followed the instruction here: 
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#-provided-configuration and added the following line to my `build.sbt`

```
run in Compile <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in(Compile, run), runner in(Compile, run))
```

This works when I call `sbt run` from the command line, but when I try to run it from InteliJ I still get the exception.

I though that I could use the `Project.inTask` method of `sbt` but I can not figure out how to do it. I would love to do a dumb simple `if-else` statement something like

```
if(i am running assembly){
  Dependencies.dependenciesProvided 
}else{
  Dependencies.dependenciesAll
}
```

To put this in terms of `sbt`:

```
lazy val `root` = project.in(file("."))
  .settings(common)
  .settings(inTask(assembly)(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.dependenciesProvided))
  .settings(inTask(???)(libraryDependencies ++ Dependencies.dependenciesAll))
```

Do you have any idea how to basically invert the scope `inTask(assembly)` and provide the dependencies in *all other cases other than assemly*?

Is it even possible?

Thanks